# This text appears to be labeling V-し・V-せず・Adj-なく・N-に as present, V-して・V-しないで・Adj-なくて・N-で as past. Why?

Tags: grammar

I found a table at [this page](http://homepage3.nifty.com/jgrammar/grammar/jgr_part.htm) that seems to be labeling Vし・Vせず・Adjなく・Nに as present tense, and Vして・Vしないで・Adjなくて・Nで as past tense. Please teach me about this distinction in the above words.

Comment: It looks like the "participle" name for て is pretty old, [going back to the 1800s](http://books.google.co.jp/books?id=lSryAAAAMAAJ&lpg=RA1-PA82&ots=VuYPVB2g5A&pg=RA1-PA81). In Martin's 1975 *Reference Grammar of Japanese*, "participle" for て is listed in the index as a term taken from *Bernard Bloch on Japanese* (1970), and in Hasegawa's 1996 paper [*The (Non-Vacuous) Semantics of TE-Linkage in Japanese*](http://socrates.berkeley.edu/~hasegawa/TE-Linkage/TE-linkage.html), she says Teramura used the term "past participle" in 活用語尾・助動詞・補助動詞とアスペクト (1969), so it's been used more recently, too.

Comment: So the author of this web page didn't invent the "past participle" term themselves, it seems―maybe you could track down the Bloch or Teramura sources and see if they give an explanation.  (Note that the presence or absence of て is the difference between the two lists of forms you present: it's part of し**て**, しない**で**, なく**て**, and **で** but absent from し, せず, なく,  and に.)

Comment: @snailboat Really impressive research! Mind answerfying it so I can vote for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They seem to be attempting to draw a distinction between *sequential coordination* forms and *simultaneous coordination* forms.

し・せず・なく・に are (theoretically) *simultaneous* coordination. The state/action they describe is true/occurring *while* whatever next thing is true/occurring:

> 本を読み、テレビを見た。
>
> He read a book and watched television (at the same time).

して・しないで・なくて・で are (theoretically) *sequential* coordination. The state/action they describe is true/occurring *before* whatever next thing is true/occurring:

> 本を読んで、テレビを見た。
>
> He read a book and (then) watched television.

In modern Japanese the distinction mostly isn't bothered with, though, and instead the differences work out something like this:

し is literary (書き言葉) / して is colloquial (話し言葉)

せず (/しなくて) is 'without doing' / しないで is 'instead of doing'

なく is literary / なくて is colloquial

「Xに、」 isn't really used as 'is X, and' in modern Japanese / 「Xで、」 is

(though correct me if I'm wrong, I'm not as sure on the last two)

Comment: Yeah, that literary/colloquial divide is what I'm familiar with. Do you know what those two, "sequential coordination" and "simultaneous coordination," are called in Japanese?

Comment: I don't, but I'd love to find out if someone else does!

Comment: So where did you get "simultaneous coordination"/"sequential coordination" from?

Comment: Came up with them on the spot ^_^

Comment: That's less than helpful in this case! :)